# SQL order by variable in inner statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM backstage 
WHERE backstage_id IN (
    SELECT backstage_id 
    FROM visitor_counter 
    WHERE backstage_id !=0 
    GROUP BY backstage_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT( DISTINCT ( ip_address ) ) DESC 
) 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

I get the results I want, but I would like to order it by `COUNT( DISTINCT ( ip_address ) ) DESC` as the inner question does.

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go and see if it gives you what you're after:

```
select bs.*
from backstage bs
inner join
(
select backstage_id,count(distinct ip_address) as distIpCount
from visitor_counter
where backstage_id !=0
group by backstage_id
) vc on vc.backstage_id = bs.backstage_id
order by vc.distIpCount desc
limit 0,100;
```